# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado EN PYCHARM

Tags: python, pycharm, ffmpeg

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    from pydub import AudioSegment \
    song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(r"C:\Users\Peter\workspace\Bot_Telegram\Audio de Pedro.mp3")
    song.export(r"C:\Users\Peter\workspace\Bot_Telegram\Audio convertido.wav", format="wav")
```

Y me devuelve este error

> C:\Users\Peter\workspace\Bot_Telegram\venv\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
> warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
> C:\Users\Peter\workspace\Bot_Telegram\venv\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
> warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Peter\workspace\Bot_Telegram\probadera.py", line 5, in 
> song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(r"C:\Users\Peter\workspace\Bot_Telegram\Audio de Pedro.mp3")
> File "C:\Users\Peter\workspace\Bot_Telegram\venv\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 796, in from_mp3
> return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
> File "C:\Users\Peter\workspace\Bot_Telegram\venv\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
> info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
> File "C:\Users\Peter\workspace\Bot_Telegram\venv\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
> res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
> File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
> File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
> hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Comment: Al parecer faltan los ejecutables para reproducir el archivo: `Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv`. Revisa que tengas instalado ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví el problema, al instalar ffmpeg debía copiar los archivos de la carpeta bin a la carpeta en la que estaba almacenado el script